# How to export multiple data-table into single excel sheet?

Tags: datatable, datatables

How to export content of multiple datatable into single excel sheet?

Comment: What database system hosts the data? Do you have access to SSIS?

Comment: Hi ,
I am talking about J-query data-table on the front side. Though we are using SQL server.

Comment: Oh sorry, I do not know the answer.